# Transform nested dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to know a pythonic way to convert the following dict in python:

```
a = {1: {'region': 'us-west'
     },

 2: {'region': 'us-west'
     }
 }
```

to be in the form of:

```
new_a = {'us-west': {1: {'data': {},
                     'metadata': {}
                     },
                 2: {'data': {},
                     'metadata': {}
                     }
                 }
     }
```

Comment: I dunno a pythonic way, but there's probably a _pandaic_ way.

Comment: Also, show your efforts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really told us what you're looking for in specific, or provided a more general dataset, but you can try this:

```
new_a = {}
for key in a.keys():
    if a[key]['region'] not in new_a:
        new_a[a[key]['region']] = {}
    new_a[a[key]['region']][key] = { 'data': {}, 'metadata':{}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
c = {1: {'region': 'us-west'
  },

  2: {'region': 'us-west'
    }
}
new_a = {b['region']:{i:{'data':{}, 'metadata':{}} for i in c} for a, b in c.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'us-west': {1: {'data': {}, 'metadata': {}}, 2: {'data': {}, 'metadata': {}}}}
```